# How to read the name of the App Service Plan used an App Service with Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

Given the name of an Azure App Service, I want to be able to find the name of the App Service plan. 
I've inspected the object returned by Get-WebApp but it doesn't contain any reference to the App Service Plan used.

Comment: What was your solution in the end?  Get-AzResource doesn't seem to have the information and neither does Get-WebApp ... just seems really odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this bit:

```
Get-AzWebApp | Select-Object name, serverfarmid
```

this will return Web App name and the Service Plan Id.

```
( Get-AzWebApp | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerFarmId ) -split '/' | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: I've noticed the ServerFarmId too, however that's not just the name of App Service Plan. Problem is that I need the Name to be able to retrieve the App Service Plan using the Get-AzAppServicePlan command. 
The only thing that I could do would be to do a string split to get the part of the ID I need